# NullPointerException after Facebook Login in Android app

Tags: android, facebook-login

Getting a NPE at onActivityResult after Facebook login in my app. Seems to work fine with most users,but some users are reporting this problem. I am using SDK 3.5.2.

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {------------}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=0, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {----------------------------------}: java.lang.NullPointerException at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3170) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3185) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:132) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2071) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4669) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:876) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:634) at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=0, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {-----------------------}: java.lang.NullPointerException at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3557) at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3157) ... 12 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at -----------------------------(LogIn.java:720) at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3905) at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3553) ... 13 more java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=0, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {----------------------------------}: java.lang.NullPointerException at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3557) at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3157) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3185) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:132) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2071) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4669) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:876) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:634) at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at ------------------------------------(LogIn.java:720) at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3905) at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3553) ... 13 more java.lang.NullPointerException at ------------------------------------(LogIn.java:720) at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3905) at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3553) at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3157) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3185) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:132) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2071) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4669) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:876) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:634) at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

Here is my code on this line.

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode , data);
    onActivityResult = true;
}
```

Comment: Check if Session.getActiveSession() returns null via debugging your app! The Logcat is quite clear `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at co.acjs.cricdecode.LogIn.onActivityResult(LogIn.java:720)`

Comment: but it is working on for most people. and not working for some... how can that be possible

Comment: Is it possible that your context is null? Someone please comment.

Comment: @A.S. I am not getting null at Session.getActiveSession(). no idea whats going wrong. It works perfectly fine for me, but not for some of my users.

Comment: Are they logged in? Maybe they canceled the Login, Like in the FB Samples check if getActiveSession() != null and only then handle it. Nevertheless, your onactivityResult maybe called by another startIntentByresulr, so only do a getActiveSession() when you get a result from the fb sdk by getting the resultcode

Comment: @A.S. This activity on consists of the login button. Therefore onActivityResult can only be called if user is trying to login. Thus, if user is getting null pointer, there is something going wrong with the facebook login. Also, simply putting a try catch would not help. I need to identify whats going wrong and give user an option to correct it. What are your thoughts?

Comment: It also returns null when the user canceled the login, or has no internet connection, so please check  `if(Session.getActiveSession() != null)` before you work with the session

Comment: i tried cancelling the login.. my app did not crash. I also tried with no internet connection... still it did not crash. Can't figure out why it crashes for my users

Comment: @A.S. how can i check if the onActivityResult is called by Facebook Login? I see that the requestCode=64206. Is this requestCode unique to Facebook?

Comment: HI@sheetal_158 : I am also facing same issue. For some of my users, app crashes. Did you find any proper solution

Comment: did you guys find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

```
// [START onActivityResult]
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {    // Taken
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED&&resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {
        mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }// Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}
```